# Navigation & View Controller questions

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I'm experimenting with ViewControllers & NavigationControllers in Interface Builder trying to get a better grasp of what's tied to what and why... I'm struggling with a scenario that has confused me. Hopefully someone can set me straight...

Say I start with your typical iPhone template View-Based Application and I display a view which is handled by view controller (viewController). Then after a certain event I'd like to replace that view with a "typical" Navigation-Based View (rootVC). I'd like to create as much as possible in IB. My questions have to do with how to show rootVC and remove all traces of the previous viewController as user will never need to return and where/how to wire in the navController in IB. Currently when it's time to show the rootVC I do the following in my viewController:

```
RootVC *rvc = [[RootVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootVC" bundle:nil];
[rvc.view setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];

ViewTestAppDelegate *appDelegate = (ViewTestAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
self.rootVC = rvc;
[rvc release];
[appDelegate.viewController.view removeFromSuperview];
[appDelegate.window addSubview:rootVC.view];
[appDelegate.viewController release];
```

rootVC displays except viewController still has a retain count of 1?!?

Also, where should rootVC's navigationController be instantiated? Having started with the View-Based template the MainWindow.xib contains an object for the viewController (which has its own ViewController.xib) an appDelegate and a UIWindow. My RootVC.xib contains a UITableView. Do I need yet another intermediary view controller that will have another ApplicationDelegate object that I wire up to a UIWindow object and a UINavigationController? The View Controller that comes along with IB's Navigation Controller object would then be set to my RootVC class?

Sorry for the verbosity. It's difficult for me to explain. Because some objects in IB are proxies and some are "real" it's sometimes confusing (to me) when trying "new" things out what's required, where & when. Basically I want to know to go about setting up one view leading to another with no way back to first view. 2nd view basically becomes the "main" root spawning off in many directions...

Comment: I personally prefer not to use IB for iPhone Dev, because it's pretty easy to make iPhone UIs. IB is better for making complex UIs (i.e. on OS X, not iPhone).

Comment: @Mk12: Don't fear the Interface Builder: http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/10/dont-fear-interface-builder.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out by putting a reference to the viewController in the MainWindow nib and then autoreleasing the viewController after I added the navigationController & rootVC to the UIWindow. Learned another thing or two about IB along the way. Pretty powerful...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the navigation-based iPhone application template and presenting your one-time view as a modal view on top of the root view.